# Does flagging ever affect anyone's rep?

Tags: discussion, flagging, reputation

The title sums up my question nicely: does flagging ever affect anyone's rep?

More specifically, if I flag a post as anything will the flagged user lose reputation at all? I know some flags, such as reasons to close, or not an answer, don't affect rep. However, I vaguely recall reading somewhere that sometimes, flags can remove rep or something (I can't find it anywhere though). Is this true or am I just imagining things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A successful *spam* or *offensive* flag will incur a 100 reputation penalty to the user who posted the content, where successful is defined as a total of six flags on that post from different users. The penalty can be reversed by moderators.

Comment: So it has to be flagged by six users, rather than just deemed helpful?

Comment: Yes, unless the moderator also explicitly flags as spam or offensive, and not just marks it helpful.

Comment: I wonder where I saw this?...

Comment: There's also the automatic downvote if a question is closed as, I think, Off Topic or Not Constructive.

Comment: Really. I always thought the mods just did that manually because of some protocol or something.

Comment: I was [mistaken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati) -- if a question is Off Topic or Not a Real Question, it will get a downvote from the Community user.

Comment: Does this 100-point penalty get factored in to rep recalculation on suspended users?

Comment: @AndrewLeach The 100-point penalty applies also to suspended users. As usual, the reputation for suspended users is recalculated when suspension ends; at the point, if they had a post that was marked as spam, or offensive by the necessary number of users, they get 100 points detracted from their reputation.